# How to close the modal dialog box in MVC View?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am developing ASP.NET MVC application.

I have used boostrap for it.

I have shown a modal popup dialog box when user click on the the link called 'Show Stock' 
(You can see it in image.)

I have shown OK and cancel button on box.

The Problem is , When I click on cancel button it box get close, but only at first time.
If I again open dialog and click on cancel button box disappears and plain black screen appears not the parent screen.

I just want to close the modal box. without mentioning the URL to the cancel button.
Is that possible ?

Here is my code...

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {



        $('#closeA').live('click', function(){
            alert("asd");
            $("body").remove( "div.modal-backdrop  in");

        });



        $('#lnkAddProduct').click(function () {

            // alert("Infuction");

            var rIndex = $("select.clsProductId").length;


            var ndate =  new Date();

            var time = ndate.getMilliseconds();

            var IDD = rIndex + time;



              $('#ProductList').append("<div  class='span12' style='margin-left:0px' ><div class='span3'><select class='clsProductId '  name='ProductId' id='ddProductList_"+IDD+"' style = 'font-size:12px;width:200px;margin-right:10px;margin-left:20px;' onchange='get("+IDD+")'/> </div><div id='ProductCode_"+IDD+"' class='span1'  style=' margin-left:30px;'></div><div id='Weight_"+IDD+"' class='span1' style=' margin-left:90px;'> </div><input type='text' id='Quantity_"+IDD+"' class='clsQuantity'  name='Quantities' style='width:50px; margin-left:35px;' onblur='StockLinkVisible("+IDD+");' /> <a href='#' style='font-size:14px;text-decoration:none;font-weight:bold; color :#ee8929; margin-left:20px;' id='lnkRemove_"+IDD+"' class='clsRemove'  onclick='removeElement(" + IDD+");'>X</a><a href='#' style='font-size:14px;text-decoration:none;font-weight:bold; color:White; margin-left:20px' id='lnkStockInfo_"+IDD+"' class='clsStockInfo'  data-container='body' data-toggle='popover' data-placement='left' data-content='Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus.' onclick='ShowStockInformation("+IDD+");'>Check Stock</a></div>");


            getProductList(IDD);


        });



    });







    function StockLinkVisible(cnt) {
        $('#lnkStockInfo_'+ cnt).show();
        $('#lnkStockInfo_'+ cnt).css("color", "#ee8929");

    }

    function DisplayAmendAdvancedPaidAmountAlert()
    {


        $('div').remove('#dataConfirmModal');

        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        if (!$('#dataConfirmModal').length) {

            $('body').append('<div id="dataConfirmModal" class="modal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="dataConfirmLabel" aria-hidden="true">  <div class="modal-header">        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" id="btnClose1"> × </button>        <h5 id="dataConfirmLabel">Stock Availability at different locations.</h5> </div><div class="modal-body" >    <table style="width:530px"><tr> <th style="width:120px">Bhivandi </th><th>Worli</th><th>Santacruze</th> <th> Saki-Naka</th> </tr>    <tr> <td><div >60 </div></td>         <td><div>3</div></td>           <td><div >60 </div></td>         <td><div>3</div></td> </tr>             </table> </div> <div class="modal-footer">       <button type="button" id="btnOk1"  class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" >OK</button> <button type="button" id="closeA"  class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" >Cancel</button> </div></div> ');   
            }       
            $('#dataConfirmModal').find('.modal-body').text($(this).attr('data-confirm'));
            $('#dataConfirmOK').attr('href', href);
            $('#dataConfirmModal').modal({show:true});


    }




</script>
```

Here is the image...

[image]

When I open the dialog box , every time Div with "modal-backdrop  in"  class get added and I cant remove it... I have checked this in Inspect Element window of Google chrome...

Check the below image...

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read carefully the modal documentation.

> If a remote url is provided, content will be loaded via jQuery's load
>   method and injected into the .modal-body

**Edited Section:**

try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function DisplayAmendAdvancedPaidAmountAlert()
    {
       $( "div.modal-backdrop.in" ).remove();
       $('div').remove('#dataConfirmModal');
       // Cal();

        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        if (!$('#dataConfirmModal').length) {
            $('body').append('<div id= "container" ><div id="dataConfirmModal" class="modal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="dataConfirmLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="width: 500px;"><div class="modal-header"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button><h6 id="dataConfirmLabel">Stock Availibility at diffrent locations</h6></div><div class="modal-body "><h4>Stocks</h4><br/>     <table>        <thead>          <tr>              <td>Bhivandi</td>              <td>Santacruze</td>              <td>Worli</td>        </tr>        </thead>        <tbody>            <tr>                <td>12</td>                <td>122</td>                <td>54</td>            </tr>        </tbody>         </table></div>     <div class="alert alert-info" style="display:none;margin:5px" id="alertMessage"> </div><div class="modal-footer"><button id="closeA" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancel</button><a class="btn btn-primary" id="dataConfirmOK">OK</a></div></div></div> ');      

            }       
            $('#dataConfirmModal').find('.modal-body').text($(this).attr('data-confirm'));
            $('#dataConfirmOK').attr('href', href);
           $('#dataConfirmModal').modal({show:true});



            }
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#closeA').live('click', function(){
        $('#container').hide();
     });
});
</script>
```

Comment: No, Not working... When I open in second time and try to close it...it again showing the black screen... I have to double click on black screen then only can see parent window...

Comment: No... Its not working... Its not removing at all... If I click on 2nd time I have to click two times on black screen... if I open the dialog on third time and close it... then I have to click on black screen three times... to go to parent window...

Comment: Another option is that you can take another div and hide that div on click of closeA button. If your requirement is still incomplete let me know I will edit my answer and give another solution.

Comment: It will be nice if you give some other solution... As I have mentioned...If I keep open and close the dialog box...I have to click on no of times on black screen, same no. of times when I open the dialog box... like if I open dialog box on 5th time and I click on cancel button then  dialog disappears and black screen appears...then I have to click on that black screen 5 times to go on parent window...

Comment: Please check your browser console in google chrome or if you are using firefox then use firebug console window may be there will be error you are getting.

Comment: I have checked it on both browsers... There is not any error...there is some conceptual issue I guess...when we click on cancel button it just remove the dialog box...not the layer which we have added...so each time when we open the dialog new layer comes on older layer so I have to click n-number of times on black screen same as n number of times I have open the dialog box...

Comment: Yeah nice. @Paddo Yes use .on() but for dynamic content .click() is not working.

Comment: For dynamic html content use this:
`$(document).on('click', 'selector', function()
{
// your code
});`

Comment: tried...but no luck...   $(document).on('click', '#closeA', function() { 
                         $('#dataConfirmModal').remove();
});

Comment: have you inserted that code in `$(document).ready(function(){});` and also insert alert('test') in click event whether event is firing or not?

Comment: ya its firing... Dialog closing or remove is not the issue...how to remove modalbackdrop in class which generated automatically everytime...

Comment: add this in your javascript function to remove the modalbackdrop `$( $("body" ).remove( "div.modalbackdrop" );`

Comment: try this:
`$( "div.modal-backdrop.in" ).remove();` and make sure modal-backdrop should not be duplicate.

Comment: I dont add modal-backdrop , it get add automatically everytime... Thats the issue...

Comment: Yes this is because you are using bootstrap library as dynamic content when it initially loads then modal-backdrop is automatically loads. I think you need to place remove modal-backdrop on function call. Please see my edited answer above.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your efforts.... Just small query, What if I want to add the data runtime inside the modal.... Right now I have added the table and its rows design time...now I want to add data to it runtime... Thanks again...

Comment: Yeah you can add it by using Jquery $.ajax call. But make it simpler because sometimes alot of scripts make more complexity.

Comment: OK...I know its going to be complex...but cant help, its requirement... I am going to post this issue soon... hope you don't mind If I ask for help to you...

Comment: Yeah sure.. No prob. Please share link also..:)

Answer (score 1):

You should have `dismiss="modal"` as attribute on your cancel button or try the following:

`$("#yourHideCloseButton").on('click', function(){
    $(this).closest(".modal").modal('hide');
});`

Try that, it should close the modal, **don't** try to remove/delete the actual `div`

Comment: Tried this, but no luck...       $('#closeA').live('click', function(){
           
            $(this).closest(".modal").modal('hide');
        });

Comment: Could you create a JSFiddle example of your page? This code should work in a normal and dynamic scenario.
+ refrain from using .live()

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following:

```
$('#dataConfirmModal').dialog('close');
```

Try using the following on click of Cancel:

```
 $('#dataConfirmModal').remove();
```

or

```
$('#dataConfirmModal').parent().remove();
```

Comment: $('#dataConfirmModal').dialog('close');

Comment: No... Its not working... Its not removing at all... If I click on 2nd time then I have to click two times on black screen... if I open the dialog on third time and close it... then I have to click on black screen three times... to go to parent window...and so on...it means...it not completely removing it...

Comment: $("#dataConfirmModal").dialog("destroy");